# How to link against just built libraries in autotools project

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

How can I link an executable in say `test` subdirectory of an autotools project  against a library, say libfoo, that is just built from files in `src` directory of same project?

Makefile.am looks like:

```
SUBDIRS = src . test
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4
```

src/Makefile.am:

```
ACLCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = \
    foo.cpp
foo_includedir = $(includedir)/foo
foo_include_HEADERS = \
    foo.hpp
```

test/Makefile.am:

```
ACLCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4
check_PROGRAMS = footest
footest_SOURCES = \
    main.cpp
footest_LDADD = ?????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy: `footest_LDADD = ../src/libfoo.la`

This works for 'out-of-tree' builds, e.g., if you invoke `configure` from another directory (not `./configure`).

Comment: Yeh, but looks gross. I don't feel good with relative paths by the way.

Comment: @sorush-r - you could also use the `builddir` and/or `top_builddir`  variables if it makes you more comfortable.